# Including text with quotes within a formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button coded to reset a spreadsheet with the following line in VBA:-

```
Range("F6") = "=IF(AND(vtype=TRUE,U41>0,vatable=FALSE),vatrate*100&"% VAT",IF(AND(vtype=TRUE,matchnew>1,vatable=TRUE),"VAT Exempt",""))"
```

When this button is clicked an error appears, it says that the `%` sign is an illegal character.

Please advise what is incorrect.

Comment: That is not VBA, that is a cell formula. They are two very different things.

Comment: If you are using VBA to assign the Formula property of a Range object then you would need to escape the double-quote characters

Comment: I should have explained the question better.  I have a button coded to reset a spreadsheet with the following line coded as:- Range("F6") = "=IF(AND(vtype=TRUE,U41>0,vatable=FALSE),vatrate*100&"% VAT",IF(AND(vtype=TRUE,matchnew>1,vatable=TRUE),"VAT Exempt",""))" - It's when this button is clicked that the illegal character error appears.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a test, I named a cell 'vatrate', then put `=vatrate*100&"%V VAT"` in another cell and it evaluated with no problem.

1. Put your cursor in the cell where this formula is
2. Click on 'Formulas' on the ribbon
3. In the 'Formula Auditing' section of the ribbon, click on 'Evaluate Formula'

That will allow you to walk through your formula one evaluation at a time so you can see exactly what Excel's seeing as it's evaluating it. That will tell you where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Range("F6") = "=IF(AND(vtype=TRUE,U41>0,vatable=FALSE),vatrate*100&""% VAT"",IF(AND(vtype=TRUE,matchnew>1,vatable=TRUE),""VAT Exempt"",""""))"
```

Excel is not objecting to `%` but to `"` without being escaped (with `"`).